# Is there any point to hint arrays of Java classes (non-primitive arrays)?

Tags: arrays, clojure

I tend to hint every java wrapper with the output type, however I wonder if hinting arrays of classes has any point. For instance:

```
(defn get-array
  ^"[Ljava.lang.String;"
  [^CharacterGenerator c s]
  ...)
```

Thanks

Comment: I verified this with decompiler, and such annotation has no effect. Function in both cases (with annotation and without) returns Object.

Comment: @generateme At the bytecode level, every Clojure function returns an Object (except those that are hinted to return primitives). A typehint tells *client* code to insert a cast if it will help.

Answer (score 1):

It has just as much point as hinting any other object-returning function. If a client uses the result in a way that would require reflection on an un-hinted function, then with a hinted function a cast will be inserted instead. For arrays, this would usually mean a call to `aget`, `alength`, or `aset`. But it could also help if the array is being passed as an argument to an overloaded method, if the array's type can help resolve the overload.